# For which $a$ do we have $\int_{\gamma} (\frac {1}{z} +\frac{a}{z^3})e^z dz=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)=(\frac {1}{z} +\frac{a}{z^3})e^z$ for $z\ne 0$. I need to find all values of $a$ for which $\int_{\gamma}f(z) dz=0$ for every closed curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$ that is partially $C^1$. For each of these values of $a$ Ι have to find $F$ such that $F'(z)=f(z)$ for $z\ne 0$.

Any help, please? Should I focus on finding the $F$ or should I determine the values of $a$ first and then construct $F$? I thought I could have $F(z)=\int_{z_0}^z f(w)dw$ for some $z_0$, but I got stuck because I don't have a convex space.

Comment: First find $a$. I suppose you have already seen the residue theorem, but if not, splitting the sum and applying Cauchy's integral formula works too. Then, if you know that the integral over any closed (sufficiently regular) curve is $0$, you know that $$\int_{z_0}^z f(w)\,dw$$ doesn't depend on the choice of the path connecting $z_0$ and $z$.

Comment: Do you know Cauchy's integral theorem?

Comment: We know Cauchy's theorem for triangles. The residue theorem, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: Integrate by parts twice.
$$ \int \dfrac{e^z\;dz}{z^3} = -\dfrac{e^z}{2 z^2} - \dfrac{e^z}{2z} + \dfrac{1}{2} \int \dfrac{e^z\; dz}{z} $$
What does that tell you about 
$$ \int_\gamma f(z)\; dz$$
Note that $\int_\gamma \dfrac{e^z\; dz}{z} \ne 0$, e.g. for a small circle around $0$.